# Microsoft Teams proactive app installation in Teams

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm creating a bot for MS Teams and using Node.js. As far as I understand, a user can install a bot for himself and start communicating 1 to 1. He can also install a bot in a Team using @Get Bot and start a conversation with him. Can I make it so that when the user installed the bot for himself and created the Team, then the bot was already installed there. I found this in the documentation
[Proactive app installation in Teams.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=csharp#proactive-app-installation-in-teams)
I tried to do these steps myself by adding permissions and setting up the manifest, but nothing worked for me. And I also wanted to ask a question if it will turn out so that it will not work on personal accounts

Comment: For a 1:1 conversation between the bot and a user (personal scope) the event is only sent the very first time the bot is installed. Technically, it is sent when the conversation is created between the bot and the user. If the user uninstalls the bot, this conversation is not deleted, so if the user then re-installs the bot the event is not sent.
For Group Chats and Channels the event will be sent each time the bot is installed. This is because each time the bot is uninstalled from this context, it is actually completely removed from the conversation, so an uninstall triggers the event.

Answer (score 0):

for better understanding posting answer from comments:

For a 1:1 conversation between the bot and a user (personal scope) the event is only sent the very first time the bot is installed. Technically, it is sent when the conversation is created between the bot and the user. If the user uninstalls the bot, this conversation is not deleted, so if the user then re-installs the bot the event is not sent. For Group Chats and Channels the event will be sent each time the bot is installed. This is because each time the bot is uninstalled